# Sorting strings lexicographically based upon certain character order

Tags: r, sorting, lexicographic-ordering

I am working my way through the Rosalind problems and have become stuck on the problem [Ordering Strings of Varying Length Lexicographically](https://rosalind.info/problems/lexv/).

So far I have succesfully managed to create all the right permutations of letters of varying lengths. The main issue is now how to sort them based on the order the letters were supplied.

The example input are the letters `D N A`. But can be at most 12 unique letters in n <= 4 permutations.

For the example n = 3.
This yields 39 different permutations with replications, but these are then to be sorted lexicographically in the order of `D` before `N` before `A`.

Meaning that the correct order is:

| Correct | Incorrect |
| --- | --- |
| D | A |
| DD | AA |
| DDD | AAA |
| DDN | AAD |
| DDA | AAN |
| DN | AD |
| DND | ADA |
| DNN | ADD |
| DNA | ADN |
| DA | AN |
| DAD | ANA |
| DAN | AND |
| DAA | ANN |
| ... | ... |
| AAD | NNA |
| AAN | NND |
| AAA | NNN |

My first thought was to convert them to factors with levels and then attempt to sort them based on their levels but I cannot quite make it work.

so far I create the list of all permutations and then attempt to sort it, but don't know how to get the sorting to follow the given order of `D N A`

```
text_input <- c("D", "N", "A")
n <- 3

empty_df <- data.frame(matrix("", ncol = n))

temp_df <- data.frame()

for (i in n:1) {
  temp_df <- data.frame(arrangements::permutations(text_input, k = i, replace = TRUE))
  empty_df <- bind_rows(empty_df, temp_df)
}

result_df <- replace(empty_df, is.na(empty_df), "") |> 
  unite(col = combined, everything(), sep = "", remove = FALSE) |> 
  mutate(across(2:(n+2), ~ factor(.x, levels = text_input)),
         across(2:(n+2), ~ str_replace_na(.x, replacement = "")))

result_vec <- tail(result_df$combined, -1)
```

Comment: FYI, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` (and `bind_rows(empty_df, temp_df)`) works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- bind_rows(out);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the sample data you have, `Correct`, randomized to ensure we get the order right.

```r
quux <- structure(list(Correct = c("D", "DD", "DDD", "DDN", "DDA", "DN", "DND", "DNN", "DNA", "DA", "DAD", "DAN", "DAA", "AAD", "AAN", "AAA"), Incorrect = c("A", "AA", "AAA", "AAD", "AAN", "AD", "ADA", "ADD", "ADN", "AN", "ANA", "AND", "ANN", "NNA", "NND", "NNN")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L), class = "data.frame")
set.seed(42)
quuxR <- quux[sample(nrow(quux)),]
quuxR$Correct
#  [1] "D"   "DDA" "AAA" "DNA" "DA"  "DDN" "DD"  "AAD" "DNN" "DND" "DAD" "DAA" "AAN" "DAN" "DDD" "DN" 

ltrs <- c("D", "N", "A")
inds <- lapply(strsplit(quuxR$Correct, ""), match, table = ltrs)
inds <- lapply(inds, `length<-`, max(lengths(inds)))
quuxR$Correct[do.call(order, c(do.call(Map, c(f=c, inds)), list(na.last = FALSE)))]
#  [1] "D"   "DD"  "DDD" "DDN" "DDA" "DN"  "DND" "DNN" "DNA" "DA"  "DAD" "DAN" "DAA" "AAD" "AAN" "AAA"
identical(quux$Correct, quuxR$Correct[do.call(order, c(do.call(Map, c(f=c, inds)), list(na.last = FALSE)))])
# [1] TRUE
```

Steps:

1. `strsplit(.., "")` splits a string into individual letters.
2. `match(.., table=ltrs)` replaces a letter with the index in `ltrs`, which gives us the proper priority/sort of the letters.
3. `` `length<-` `` is because we are going to subsequently `rbind` them, but that will only work if they all have the same length. Doing this step (along with `max(lengths(..))` fills the shorter vectors with `NA`s so that all sub-vectors have the same number of elements.
4. `do.call(Map, c(f=c, inds))` transposes a list with `m` vectors length `n` into a `n`-length list, each with `m` elements. This is very helpful to have for the next step ...
5. `do.call(order, ..)` is similar to calling `order(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]])` (if `L` is the transposed list), but more programmatic. We add `list(na.last=FALSE)` as an argument to the list of vectors so that we can get the right ordering of shorter strings.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I do not get the correct order though. With the seed I get the same result from `quuxR$Correct`.  But the `quuxR$Correct(do.call` gives back a different order 
`quuxR$Correct[do.call(order, c(do.call(Map, c(f=c, inds)), list(na.last = FALSE)))]
 [1] "D"   "DDA" "AAA" "DNA" "DA"  "DDN" "DD"  "AAD" "DNN" "DND" "DAD" "DAA" "AAN" "DAN" "DDD" "DN"`

Comment: Godrim, there was a typo in my answer (`quux`-vs-`quuxR`), the crux is that if you use the `lapply(strsplit(..), ...); inds <- ...; ...` on your vector, does it work? Please try again.

Comment: it is now giving the expected results! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chartr` and `order` its result and use this to subset the original unordered vector.

```
x <- c("DD", "AAN", "DDD", "DNA", "DAA", "DAD", "DDN", "DDA", "DND", 
       "DAN", "DNN", "DA", "AAA", "AAD", "DN", "D") #Unordered
y <- c("D", "DD", "DDD", "DDN", "DDA", "DN", "DND", "DNN", "DNA", "DA",
       "DAD", "DAN", "DAA", "AAD", "AAN", "AAA") #Target order

z <- x[order(chartr("DNA", "ABC", x))]
identical(z, y)
#[1] TRUE

z
# [1] "D"   "DD"  "DDD" "DDN" "DDA" "DN"  "DND" "DNN" "DNA" "DA"  "DAD" "DAN"
#[13] "DAA" "AAD" "AAN" "AAA"
```

Comment: Wow, succinct and elegant!

Comment: For some reason my z becomes `"D"   "DN"  "DND" "DNN" "DNA" "DA"  "DAD" "DAN" "DAA" "AAD" "AAN" "AAA" "DD"  "DDD" "DDN" "DDA"`. No packages loaded. I think the same problem as I commented on @r2evans answer is happening here.

Comment: Can you please describe the cases, where your described observations happens, so that I can reproduce them? When I try `table(replicate(999, {. <- sample(x); identical(.[order(chartr("DNA", "ABC", .))], y)}))` I get `999` `TRUE`, what means that it has sorted the way it was asked for. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, maybe not as succinct as others.

It starts with a function which replaces the three letters `D`, `N` and `A` with the numbers `1`, `2` and `3`.

Applying this function to the unordered vector and apply `order` to this, gives an ordering vector back, with which the unordered list can be sliced.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(
    "DD", "AAN", "DDD", "DNA", "DAA", "DAD", "DDN", "DDA", "DND",
    "DAN", "DNN", "DA", "AAA", "AAD", "DN", "D"
) # Unordered

er <- function(s) {
    s1 <- stringr::str_replace_all(s, "D", "1")
    s1 <- stringr::str_replace_all(s1, "N", "2")
    s1 <- stringr::str_replace_all(s1, "A", "3")
    return(s1)
}

l1 <- order(er(x))

x[l1]
#>  [1] "D"   "DD"  "DDD" "DDN" "DDA" "DN"  "DND" "DNN" "DNA" "DA"  "DAD" "DAN"
#> [13] "DAA" "AAD" "AAN" "AAA"
```